# Configurable with Same Configuration Options but different SKUs from different Vendors

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, pricing

In Magento 1.9 , please consider this problem.

One Jersey with different colors and sizes is manifested as a Configurable in my System. (For example, with Colors: REd,Blue,Green and Sizes : AS,AM,AL,AXL)

So JERSEY-RED-AM is a Simple product in the System that can be chosen from the configurable in the website.

But for me, JERSEY-RED-AM is supplied by different sources. And they have different pricing .  So I catalog them internally as different SKUS. 
JERSEY-RED-AM : SKU1 - $10.50
JERSEY-RED-AM : SKU2 - $12.00
JERSEY-RED-AM : SKU3 - $13.00

I'd like to sell the SKU1 first as part of the configurable, then when that runs out of stock, automatically add the SKU2 to the configurable .

Is this even possible? How can I use Magento to solve this problem? is it possible to do this without custom coding? Any pre-existing extensions? 
If custom code, any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.9 doesn't have multi-level inventory tracking, so this is not possible natively.

If this must be handled by Magento, then I think you'd need to setup a unique SKU for each physical product (JERSEY-RED-AM-SKU1, JERSEY-RED-AM-SKU2, etc), then by using a cron job or an after checkout observer you would confirm the availability of the SKUs and connect the next SKU to the configurable product. [Here's an intro on programmatically adjusting configurable products.](https://inchoo.net/magento/programmatically-create-a-configurable-magento-product/)

Depending on the complexity of your inventory system, this might be better handled outside of Magento. You could export the new orders from Magento to a local inventory management system, and then have that internal system select which warehouse inventory sku is associated with a Magento sku.